# TypeError: String indices must be intergers Django

Tags: python, arrays, django, string, compiler-errors

I am trying to store a dictionary item but i receive this particular error and i can't seem to wrap my head around why
my dictionnary looks like this

```
 comment = {'en': 'The SIDHistory attribute must be cleared', 'fr': "L'attribut SIDHistory doit être effacé"}
```

and the function I use is

```
               if y.get('comment'):
                    # print('Comment :')
                    comments = y.get('comment')
                    print(comments)
                    print(comments["en"])
                    print(comments["fr"])
                    # print('     Comment in English :', comment['en'])
                    field_comment_english = comments["en"]
                    # print('     Comment in French :', comment['fr'])
                    field_comment_french = comments["fr"]
                else:
                    # print('     Comment in English : None')
                    # print('     Comment in French : None')
                    field_comment_english = 'None'
                    field_comment_french = 'None'
```

It prints the variable I want without problem but then I receive an error at the end of the compilation telling me

```
  File "/Users/cmahouve/PycharmProjects/secad/apps/rules_management/views.py", line 50, in all_rules_interpreter
    print(comments["en"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: This is not a dictionary, but a string with as content that *looks* like something that is a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a dictionary, but a string with as content that *looks* like something that is a dictionary. You can use the [**`.literal_eval(…)`** function <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) of the [**`ast`** module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to parse this into a dictionary:

```
from ast import literal_eval

if y.get('comment'):
    comments = literal_eval(y.get('comment'))
    # …
```

But the question is why this is a string, there might be a problem more upstream where the `y` is "populated" with data.

Comment: The weird thing is when i do ```print(type(y.get('comment')) is dict)``` i get true meaning that comment is indeed a dict same with  ````print(type(comments) is dict)````

Comment: i found the problem thanks to you, i printed all m y.get('comment') in the loop then i found out that the data i was receiving had a problem, it looked like this  ```{'en': 'This account must be disabled', 'fr': 'Ce compte doit être désactivé'}
Ce compte peut être supprimé ``` ````{'en': 'Value must be 0', 'fr': 'La valeur doit être 0'}```` the format on one of the received dict wasn't right thanks again